# Run a background thread in ASP.NET MVC4 - video conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, process

I am trying threading to synchronize with conversion of video with parameterized call.

```
                    StartTheThread(inputpath, outputconvertpath);
```

**This** call goes to relative threading method that is accepting arguments and starting thread in manner of conversion of video like this-

```
   public Thread StartTheThread(string inputpath, string outputconvertpath)
        {
            var t = new Thread(() => RealStart(inputpath, outputconvertpath));
            t.Start();
            return t;
        }
        public void RealStart(string inputpath, string outputconvertpath)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(this);
            try
            {
                FFMpegConverter ff = new FFMpegConverter();
                ff.ConvertMedia(inputpath, outputconvertpath, Format.mp4);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(this);
            }
        }
```

**Reference for video conversion-**

http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx

**What is not working-**

Till my call to method `StartTheThread` this works fine, But when it actually tries to process the thread in method  `RealStart`; it never starts this method in background.

I studied about locking the process here- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26130/Threads-and-Thread-Synchronization-in-C

But this didn't help me.

How can I start this thread so my conversion of video works in background?

Comment: So if you place a breakpoint on `Monitor.Enter(this);` it never fires?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, It fires, but never starts process of conversion.

Comment: Manually using `Monitor` can be tricky to get correct. Is this the only method that uses the `Monitor` functions on `this`? Any reason you've preferred to use them manually rather than using `lock()`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I didn't want to use `Lock` since I have only one process to go. It was only to give it a try whether this does it or not.